# Insert results of query 2 into query 1, but query 2 has no key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using T-SQL, I have one query that returns data regarding transactions from a table. For each transaction, there is a transaction date (the date the transaction occurred), among other columns of data. Let's just say the pseudo-code is...

```
Select TransactionDate, LoanNumber 
From   TransactionsTable
```

Now in a separate query, I simply query off the same table, but ONLY select the `MAX` transaction date. E.g. in pseudo-code...

```
Select MAX(TransactionDate) as DataDate 
From   TransactionsTable
```

I am trying to append this `MAX(TransactionDate)` to every record in the original query. The reason for this is so that I can have a *DataCurrentAsOf* or *DataDate* field, or something like that. Also, `GETDATE()` won't work because the `MAX` transaction date is very variable.

The ideal pseudo-code would read something like...

```
Select    a.TransactionDate, b.DataDate, a.LoanNumber
From      TransactionsTable a
Left Join 
(
    Select MAX(TransactionDate) as DataDate 
    From   TransactionsTable
) b on EVERYWHERE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a window function:

```
Select tt.TransactionDate, tt.LoanNumber,
       max(tt.TransactionDate) over () as DataDate
From TransactionsTable tt;
```

Your pseudo code should work if you leave out the `on` clause and replace the `left join` with a `cross join`.  However, window functions are more concise and usually faster.

Comment: Awesome...thank you for this. Great suggestion with the cross join also. That is what actually ended up working in my query. The window would have worked, except in the end, the TransactionDate column is null'd out by WHERE clauses, so the cross join was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if understand your query, but will answer based on what i got. You can achieve simply by executing the below statements:

```
SELECT @maxTransactionDate = MAX(transactiondate) from TransactionsTable 
select LoanNumber, TransactionDATE, @maxTransactionDate AS [Max Transaction Date] from TransactionsTable
```